# Would a chrome extension that copy pastes Linkedin page data against Linkedin's terms of service?

Tags: jquery, web-scraping, linkedin-api

It's pretty trivial to write an extension that will quickly let you copy some fields in a LinkedIn's page and paste it into a CRM tool.

To get full name via jquery for example

```
fullname = $('#name').children('h1').eq(0).children('span').eq(0).children('span').eq(0).text()
```

However, is this against Linkedin's terms of service?
I have read it and it says scraping is forbidden, but is this scraping? It's merely automating copy pastes for data on a single page I have access to.

Edit: To further clarify. This extension will only let you automatically copy text you are already seeing on an open Linkedin profile page you have acces to, into a CRM program that you use. It would automate the exact equivalent of: opening the Linkedin page, selecting certain text like name and email, COPY, opening CRM program, selecting respective fields, PASTE.

Comment: why the downvote? The question asks for clarification from the developer community if automating copy paste can be construed as scraping and thus against LinkedIn's TOS. This is certainly relevant and knowledge that will be available to experienced devs who have come across this use case before

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a legal not a technical question.

Comment: I agree there are legal implications to the question. However, due to the fact that the developer community is uniquely knowledgeable about the issue, I still think it's a valid question. I have on more than one occasion cleared up questions about what Facebook apps allow or not based on their TOS and my personal experience, and I'm not a lawyer but a dev. Although it's debatable, 2 downvotes certainly seem a little harsh.

Comment: You could try http://law.stackexchange.com/, but I don't know if it'd be on-topic there or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, LinkedIn does not allow scraping of public profiles.